# Different styles for different points in ComplexListPlot?

Tags: plotting, complex

I'd like to use `ComplexListPlot` to show a point and its image under a complex function, with the point and image having different styles, say different colors.

Use, for example:

```
z1 = 3 + 4 I;
f[z_] := Sin[20/z]
```

The following will do what I want:

```
pt = ComplexListPlot[{z1}, PlotRange -> {-1 - 2 I, 10 + 10 I}, 
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}];
val = ComplexListPlot[{f[z1]}, PlotRange -> {-1 - 2 I, 10 + 10 I}, 
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Green}];
Show[{pt, val}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: A complex point and its image under a complex function.]

But is there a simpler way, using a single `ComplexListPlot` expression?

I tried the following, but it just applies the first entry (with `Red`) to both points:

```
ComplexListPlot[{z1, f[z1]}, PlotRange -> {-1 - 2 I, 10 + 10 I}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[Large], Red}, {PointSize[Large], Green}}, 
 ImageSize -> Small]
```

I may be "pushing" `ComplexListPlot` to do something for which it was not really intended, but as things stand I see no other way to plot points in the complex plane in different styles while still using complex numbers and not (real,imag) pairs of reals.

Before version 12's `ComplexListPlot`, I would create the image with David Park's *Presentations* add-on application as follows:

```
Draw2D[{PointSize[Large], Red, ComplexPoint[z1], Green, 
  ComplexPoint[f[z1]]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an additional set of list braces to separate datasets, and while not needed, you can use [`Directive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive) to collect directives:

```
ComplexListPlot[
    {{z1},{f[z1]}},
    PlotRange->{-1-2 I,10+10 I},
    PlotStyle->{
        Directive[PointSize[Large],Red], (* style for first dataset *)
        Directive[PointSize[Large],Green] (* style for second dataset *)
    },
    ImageSize->Small
]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of how to use `Directive` to produce a more verbose, but possibly more readable, treatment. However, having to create a list of two lists of complex numbers seems an "excessive" way to be forced to vary the styling.

Comment: @murray If you have a single list of complex numbers, how does Mathematica know whether each number should have the same color, or each should have different colors?

Comment: With a `PlotStyle` target of form `{`*specs1*`,`*specs2*`}` where *specs1* and *specs2* are lists of styles,it would not seem unreasonable that the 1st point is treated by *specs1* and the 2nd point is treatec by *specs2* (and if there's only a single, unnested list as target of `PlotStyle`, then the targe is applied to both points). Am I missing seeing some conflict?

Answer (score 1):

You can also wrap each point with `Style`:

```
ComplexListPlot[MapThread[Style, {{z1, f@z1}, {Red, Green}}],
  PlotRange -> {-1-2 I, 10+10 I}, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], ImageSize -> Small]
```

or

```
ComplexListPlot[MapThread[Style[##, PointSize[Large]] &, {{z1, f@z1}, {Red, Green}}],
  PlotRange -> {-1 - 2 I, 10 + 10 I}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh..., I forgot about `Style`. More directly: `ComplexListPlot[{Style[z1, Red], Style[f[z1], Green]}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotRange -> {-1 - 2 I, 10 + 10 I}, 
 ImageSize -> Small]`.